# getSystemContext() of my ServiceTestCase returns null

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, servicetestcase

I have a test with the code below, but I get a NullpointerException because getSystemContext() returns null. 
 My project looks as follows:

```
~/trunk/src/<packages>/<classes>
~/trunk/test/<packages/<testclasses>
~/trunk/<static android dirs>
~/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml
```

Please tell me what I've done wrong.

```
    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
    public class MyServiceTest extends ServiceTestCase<MyService> {


    public MyServiceTest() {
       super(MyService.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartable() {
       Context mockContext = getSystemContext();
       Log.d("testStartable", "testContext " + mockContext.getClass().getCanonicalName());
       Intent startIntent = new Intent();
       startIntent.setClass(mockContext, MyService.class);
       mockContext.startService(startIntent);
       assertNotNull(getService());
    }
   }
```

Comment: Are you using Robolectric or Android Test Project write your test?

Comment: The tests are run in the maven build process. To prevent stacktraces about stub classes I use Roboelectric to run the unit tests.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am facing the same thing.